# No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"spree/taxons", :id=>nil}

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Hello RoR programmers,

I get stuck in customized spree application codes brought errors after upgrade to rails 5.1.5.

puma logged this error:

> Error during failsafe response: No route matches {:action=>"show",
>   :controller=>"spree/taxons", :id=>nil}, possible unmatched
>   constraints: [:id]
>   /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:55:in
>   `generate'
>
>   /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:748:in`
>   generate'
>   /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:779:in
>   `generate'
>
>   /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/routing-filter-0.6.1/lib/routing_filter/adapters/rails.rb:30:in`
>   block in generate'
>   /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/routing-filter-0.6.1/lib/routing_filter/filters/locale.rb:70:in
>   `around_generate'
>
>   /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/routing-filter-0.6.1/lib/routing_filter/filter.rb:11:in`
>   run'
>   /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/routing-filter-0.6.1/lib/routing_filter/chain.rb:15:in
>   `run'
>
>   /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/routing-filter-0.6.1/lib/routing_filter/adapters/rails.rb:29:in`
>   generate'
>   /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:826:in
>   `url_for'
>
>   /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:277:in`
>   call'
>   /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:335:in
>   `block (2 levels) in define_url_helper'
>
>   /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/routes_proxy.rb:42:in`
>   nested_taxons_path'
>   /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/actionpack-5.1.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/routes_proxy.rb:45:in
>   `method_missing'
>
>   /root/.rbenv/versions/2.5.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/spree_core-3.4.4/app/helpers/spree/base_helper.rb:79:in`
>   seo_url'
>   /home/ypill/wuxu18/app/views/spree/frontend/ypill/_main_nav_bar.html.erb:16:in
>   `block (3 levels) in _d16a1d9612a1846710427ba2d762257f'

app/controllers/spree/taxons_controller.rb:

```
module Spree
  class TaxonsController < Spree::StoreController
    helper 'spree/products', 'spree/taxon_filters'

    respond_to :html

    def show
      @taxon = Taxon.friendly.find(params[:id])
      return unless @taxon

      @searcher = build_searcher(params.merge(taxon: @taxon.id, include_images: true))
      @products = @searcher.retrieve_products
      @taxonomies = Spree::Taxonomy.includes(root: :children)
```

spree/frontend/config/routes.rb:

```
  # route globbing for pretty nested taxon and product paths
  get '/t/*id', to: 'taxons#show', as: :nested_taxons
```

In spree/core/app/helpers/spree/base_helper.rb:

```
def seo_url(taxon)
  spree.nested_taxons_path(taxon.permalink)
end
```

Line 79: `spree.nested_taxons_path(taxon.permalink)`
`method_missing' or undefined method`permalink' for nil:NilClass

customized _main_nav_bar.html.erb file code, puma logged error from line 16, 14, 13, 12:

```
<% @taxonomies ||= Spree::Taxonomy.includes(root: :children)  %>
<% max_level = Spree::Config[:max_level_in_taxons_menu] || 1 %>
<div class="navbar-header">
      <div class="container">
         <nav class="navbar" id="cssmenu">
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li id="home-link"
            class="<%= ('active' if @page.nil? && @taxon.id == 12) unless @taxon.nil? %>"
              data-hook><%= link_to Spree.t(:home), spree.root_path %></li>

            <%#= @taxon.inspect %>
            <% @taxonomies.each do |taxonomy| %>
              <% cache [I18n.locale, taxonomy, max_level] do %>
                    <% taxonomy.root.children.each do |taxon| %>
                      <li class="<%= (taxon.id == @taxon.id ? 'active' : '') unless @taxon.nil? %>">
                        <%= link to taxon.name, seo_url(taxon) %>">
                        </a>
                      </li>
                    <% end %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
          </ul>

        </nav>
```

Line 12:

```
<% @taxonomies.each do |taxonomy| %>
```

line 13:

```
<% cache [I18n.locale, taxonomy, max_level] do %>
```

Line 14:

```
<% taxonomy.root.children.each do |taxon| %>
```

Line 16

```
<%= link to taxon.name, seo_url(taxon) %>
```

In block (3 levels) puma seeks 'seo_url" to spree_core-3.4.4/app/helpers/spree/base_helper.rb:79 'spree.nested_taxons_path(taxon.permalink)' method missing.

main_nav_bar.html.erb worked on rails 4.2.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try this route:

```
 get '/t/*id', to: 'spree/taxons#show', as: :nested_taxons
```

Comment: It doesn't solve the error. Actual error maybe is "method missing" or "undefined method", although puma logged "No route matches"